# XE6 Ansi/Unicode-String Linker Errors (Unresolved Externals)

Tags: linker, unicode-string, ansistring, c++builder-xe6

My senario is to port my projects from XE3 to XE6.

I having these unresolved extrenals when I'm switching calling convention from C to stdcall.

Starting from there, UnicodeString(), ~UnicodeString() (any other) become unresolved.

I'd compare ustring.h between XE3 and XE6. Looks like there are many changes there.

For example : UnicodeString destructor.

In XE3, it's decalred as :

```
  __fastcall ~UnicodeString();
```

In XE6, it's decalred as :

```
  ~UnicodeString();
```

I than modified the declaration, to be :

```
  __cdecl ~UnicodeString();
```

This correct the linker error.

Is this normal, is it the right correction to do ?

To obtain the problem :

- create a new C++ package;
- create a new component, derived from TEdit, and add it to the
  package.
- build and link => all is OK;
- than go to project options, and switch calling convention to stdcall;
- build and link => unresolved external occurs;

Thanks in advance for your answers.

N. Fortin

Comment: I would suggest you file this as a regression bug to [QualityCentral](http://qc.embarcadero.com). Since compatibility classes, like `UnicodeString`, are implemented in the precompiled RTL, the headers need to match the actual calling conventions used or else you get these linker errors, not what the C++ compiler wants to use. Earlier versions forced that equality, looks like someone goofed it up in XE6

Comment: I have filed a QC report for you: [#124667 Unresolved External error in UnicodeString destructor](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=124667).

Comment: Well, that's what I've thought!.
Thanks for the QC log Remy. You're still the one !!
I'm in an evaluation context of the product, and I'm in touch with a Seller and an engeneer at Embarcadero. I'll refer them the new QC.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use 32-bit XE3 and 64-bit on XE6? If so, 64-bit generally  doesn't support multiple calling conventions, and thus nearly everything is cdecl. This is normal